# fastest way to copy values from one cell of a dataframe to another data frame if a third cell matches

Tags: python, pandas

I have a master dataframe with anywhere between 750 to 3000 rows of data.

I have a daily order dataframe with anywhere from 3000 to 5000 rows of data.

If the product code of the daily order dataframe is found in the master dataframe, I get the item cost. Otherwise, it is marked as invalid and deleted.

I currently do this via 2 for loops.  But I will have to do many more such comparisons and data updating (other fields to compare, other values to copy)
What is the most efficient way to do this?

I cannot make the column I am comparing the index column of the master dataframe.
In this case, the product code may be unique in the master and I could do a merge, but there are other cases where I may have to compare other values like supplier city which may not be unique.

I seem to be doing this repeatedly in all my Python codes and I want to learn the most efficient way to do this.

```
Order DF:
[![Order csv from which the Order DF is created][1]][1]
```

```
Master DF
[![Master csv from which Master DF is created][1]][1]
```

```
def fillVol(orderDF,mstrDF,paramC,paramF,notFound):

    orderDF['ttlVol']=0
    for i in range(len(orderDF)):
        found=False
        for row in mstrDF.itertuples():
            if (orderDF.loc[i,paramC]==getattr(row,paramC)):
                orderDF.loc[i,paramF[0]]=getattr(row,paramF[0])#mtrl cbf
                found=True
                break
        if (found==False):
            notFound.append(inv.loc[i,paramC])

    inv['ttlVol']=inv[paramF[0]]*inv[paramF[2]]
    return notFound
```

I am passing along the column names I am comparing and the column names I am filling with data because there are minor variations in naming the csv.  In the data I have shared, the material volume is CBF, in come cases it is CBM

The data columns cannot be index because there are no unique data in any of the columns, it is always a combination of values that makes them unique.

The data, in this case, is a float and numpy could be used, but in other cases like copying city names from a master, the data is a string. numpy was the suggestion to other people with a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the most efficient way of doing it - as someone who started programming with Fortran and then C, I am always for basic datatypes and this solution is not utilising basic datatype.  This is definitely a highly Pythonic solution.

```
orderDF=orderDF[orderDF[ParamF].isin(mstrDF[ParamF])]
orderDF=orderDF.reset_index(drop=True)
```

I use a left merge on the orderDF and msterDF data frames to copy all relevant values

```
orderDF=orderDF.merge(mstrDF.drop_duplicates(paramC,keep='last')[[paramF[0]]]', how='left',validate = 'm:1')
```